# Why does FOR /F pick up a space as a valid line when getting data from a file and how do I prevent this?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, psexec

So I have been working on this batch script for a while now, it's the first one I've ever written. The idea is to connect to remote machines in our domain and gather some information.

I'm using a .txt file with the IP addresses of machines in it, one per line and each separated with a comma like so.

192.168.1.1,

192.168.1.2,

192.168.1.3

For some reason, once the script reaches the last IP address in the file, it queries a blank space. Is this blank space a trailing space character? and how do I prevent this from happening?

The way I've currently got the script setup means that when a computer is unreachable, it echoes a message to the log file. So every time I run the script it will be adding an extra line saying " (BLANK SPACE)   *Machine was Unreachable*" I know it's only a minor thing but it's bugging me.

Here is my Code

```
@echo off
title Audit Script

for /F %%i in (C:\testlist.txt) DO call :test %%i

:test

ping %1 > out.txt
find "Reply" out.txt > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO sysinf
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 GOTO pingerror

:pingerror
echo %1 Unreachable
echo. >> C:\Computer-Audit.log
echo ########################################################## >> C:\Computer-Audit.log
echo MACHINE %1 was unreachable on the %date% at %time% >> C:\Computer-Audit.log
echo ########################################################## >> C:\Computer-Audit.log
echo. >> C:\Computer-Audit.log
GOTO :eof

:sysinf
psexec \\%1 -u Administrator -p g2m60gy -accepteula -nobanner -low -n 10     systeminfo | findstr "Host OS" >> C:\Computer-Audit.log

if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 GOTO reg
if errorlevel 1 GOTO test

:reg
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN (
'psexec \\%1 -u Administrator -p g2m60gy -accepteula -nobanner -low -n 10  reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Betting   Till_is1" /v DisplayVersion 2^> nul'
) DO SET DisplayName=%%B
echo Betting Till Version:     %DisplayName% >> C:\Computer-Audit.log
```

Here is what I have tried to prevent the FOR /F from querying a blank space.

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%i in (C:\testlist.txt) DO call :test %%i
```

This doesn't throw any error messages but it still queries a blank space.

```
for /F %%i in (C:\testlist.txt ^| findstr /C:" "  /v /r "^$" ) DO call :test %%i
```

This throws the error message "*The system cannot find the file |.*" and also still queries the blank space.

Also, any tips on how to improve my code would be much appreciated.

Comment: By Default, `FOR /F` skips blank lines.  You sure there isn't some other type of control character on that line?

Comment: I didn't know that. There is definitely no extra characters other than the ones stated above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a problem with a space.

In batch files, when you use a subroutine, you declare a label as the start point, but there is nothing that prevent batch file execution from reaching the code after the label.

Once your `for` command has ended processing the file, bat execution continues and the code after the label is executed, but this time `%1` is empty (well, or not, now `%1` makes reference to the first argument of the batch file), so `ping` is executed without arguments, shows its help and as it does not contain the `Reply` string (I can not test, I have a spanish locale), it is handled as a non reachable machine.

Place a `goto :eof` before the `:test` label to avoid execution to enter this code unless called.

```dos
@echo off
title Audit Script

for /F %%i in (C:\testlist.txt) DO call :test %%i

goto :eof    <- This jumps to the end of the file

:test
....
....
```

Comment: Oh, that actually makes total sense. Thank you!